# How do I get rid of this "(" using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I was moving along on a regex expression and I have hit a road block I can't seem to get around. I am trying to get rid of "(" in the middle of a line of text using regex, there were 2 but I figured out how to get the one on the end of the line. its the one in the middle I can hack out.

Here is a more complete snippet of the file which I am search through.

```
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.clientDevice = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
ide1:0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.clientDevice = "TRUE"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.networkName = "solignis.local"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
guestOSAltName = "Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)"
guestOS = "ubuntulinux"
uuid.location = "56 4d e8 67 57 18 67 04-c8 68 14 eb b3 c7 be bf"
uuid.bios = "56 4d e8 67 57 18 67 04-c8 68 14 eb b3 c7 be bf"
vc.uuid = "52 c7 14 5c a0 eb f4 cc-b3 69 e1 6d ad d8 1a e7"
```

Here is a the entire foreach loop I am working on.

```
my @virtual_machines;
foreach my $vm (keys %virtual_machines) {
    push @virtual_machines, $vm;
}
foreach my $vm (@virtual_machines) {
    my $vmx_file = $ssh1->capture("cat $virtual_machines{$vm}{VMX}");

    if ($vmx_file =~ m/^\bguestOSAltName\b\s+\S\s+\W(?<GUEST_OS> .+[^")])\W/xm) {
        $virtual_machines{$vm}{"OS"} = "$+{GUEST_OS}";
    } else {
        $virtual_machines{$vm}{"OS"} = "N/A";
    }
    if ($vmx_file =~ m/^\bguestOSAltName\b\s\S\s.+(?<ARCH> \d{2}\W\bbit\b)/xm) {
        $virtual_machines{$vm}{"Architecture"} = "$+{ARCH}";
    } else {
        $virtual_machines{$vm}{"Architecture"} = "N/A";
    }
}
```

I am thinking the problem is I cannot make a match to "(" because the expression before that is to ".+" so that it matches everything in the line of text, be it alphanumeric or whitespace or even symbols like hypens.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

This is what I am getting for an output from a hash dump.

```
$VAR1 = {
      'NS02' => {
                  'ID' => '144',
                  'Version' => '7',
                  'OS' => 'Ubuntu Linux (64-bit',
                  'VMX' => '/vmfs/volumes/datastore2/NS02/NS02.vmx',
                  'Architecture' => '64-bit'
                },
```

The part of the code block where I am working with ARCH work flawless so really what I need is hack off the "(64-bit)" part if it exists when the search runs into the ( and have it remove the preceding whitespace before the (.

What I am wanting is to turn the above hash dump into this.

```
$VAR1 = {
      'NS02' => {
                  'ID' => '144',
                  'Version' => '7',
                  'OS' => 'Ubuntu Linux',
                  'VMX' => '/vmfs/volumes/datastore2/NS02/NS02.vmx',
                  'Architecture' => '64-bit'
                },
```

Same thing minus the (64-bit) part.

Comment: Could you please provide the input pattern. Something like `Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)`. It'll help

Comment: You mean the line from the source file where it get the information?

Comment: No, the text that you're trying to match with the regex.

Comment: I added the text I am trying to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to match the contents of the string after `guestOSAltName` up to (and not including) the first `(` if present?

Then replace the first line of your code sample with

```
if ($vmx_file =~ m/^guestOSAltName\s+=\s+"(?<GUEST_OS>[^"()]+)/xm) {
```

If there always is a whitespace character before a potential opening parenthesis, then you can use

```
if ($vmx_file =~ m/^guestOSAltName\s+=\s+"(?<GUEST_OS>[^"()]+)[ "]/xm) {
```

so you don't need to strip trailing whitespace if present.

Comment: I tired telling it to exclude "() from the search but it for reason did not like the second )it would only exclude one. I will try your code.

Comment: not exactly, I am trying to match the everything between the quotes, excluding the text between ( and ) which is for something later in the script. Then I need to also strip out the quotes around the search text.

Comment: Do you mean that in a text like `"text 1 (text 2) text 3"` you would like to get `text 1 text 3` as a match result? That is not possible with a single regex.

Comment: No all of my search patterns will be words and whitespace then they will either end in (64\32-bit) or nothing and just be the end line.

Comment: Then my pattern should work. You might want to strip trailing whitespace off the result, though. This could also be done in the regex if there always is whitespace before a `(` in your input strings.

Comment: there is always whitespace before the (xx-bit) block. Unless it does not exists like it is on some of them but the if statement will take care of that.

Comment: IT WORKS! I just need to strip the trailing whitespace but it appears to work, let me test against some more arcane examples and I will let you know.

Comment: Yep its solid, I tested against several OS type selections in VMware and it displays the names correctly plus the trailing whitespace.

Comment: It just occured to me why it works, because you are looking for 1 or more of the excluded characters. Perfect!

Comment: I have added another regex that will remove the trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your regex to `/^guestOSAltName\s+=\s+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+)"/m`. What this does:

- `^` forces the match to start at the beginning of a line
- `guestOSAltName` is a string literal.
- `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace characters.
- `(?<GUEST_OS>.+)` matches all the text from after the spaces to the end of the line, catches the group and names it `GUEST_OS`. If the line could have comments, you might want to change `.+` to `[^#]+`.
- The `"`'s around the group are literal quotes.
- The `m` at the end turns on multi-line matching.

Code:

```
if ($vmx_file =~ /^guestOSAltName\s+=\s+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+)"/m) {
    print "$+{GUEST_OS}";
} else {
    print "N/A";
}
```

See it here: http://ideone.com/1xH5J

Comment: That won't work, the way I have it written up above is how it written character for character in the VMX file I am reading from a VMware server. Including the "=" and the whitespace.

Comment: I tried using your expression in place of mine, I get the same result.

Comment: @solignis Either give some more code (edit the question), or look at it working [here](http://ideone.com/IXwnt) and find out why that's working and yours isn't.

Comment: Yeah I will add more, I was keeping it lean because I did not want to irritate anyone with large blocks of code.

Comment: @solignis That's a good thing! I mean give the code you're using with my regex that is failing.

Comment: @solignis Okay, so your string is multi-line so you needed to keep multi-line mode. See updated answer and see it working [here](http://ideone.com/1xH5J). Hopefully that solves it for you!

Comment: good news, you method of simplifying the search pattern worked, but I am still getting the same results that my old code gave me. nice addition though.

Comment: @solignis Same results being the missing `)`? Have you checked that your input has that before the closing `"`? Echo the string just before attempting the match. It might be that you're modifying the string elsewhere.

Comment: yep, it has the requirments. Because I have both a result from the search pattern that ends in (64-bit) and one that does not. What I need is just search for the text ends and it runs into the ( then have it hack off that and the whitespace behind it.

Comment: Yeah very close, I had something similar like that as my first try. The problem kept running into is in some lines there is no (xx-bit) part it just end after the OS name so I have split it into 2 if statements to make it work right.

Comment: no dice, it gave me the output Ubuntu Linux (64-bit) then new line N/A, then Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Web Edition. Which does not end in (32\64-bit).

Comment: @soligins I should really test both first. Here's it without the `(64 bit)`: http://ideone.com/Z9p3P and with: http://ideone.com/tNSFF

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$match =~ s/^(.*?)\((.*?)$/$1$2/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `?` behind your counter. `?` stands for [non greedy](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm).

The regex is `/^guestOSAltName[^"]+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+?)\s*[\("]+.*$/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

foreach my $x ('guestOSAltName = "Ubuntu Linux (64-bit)"', 'guestOSAltName = "Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition"') {
    if ($x =~ m/^guestOSAltName[^"]+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+?)\s*[\("]+.*$/xm) {
        print "$+{GUEST_OS}\n";
    } else {
        print "N/A\n";
    }
    if ($x =~ m/^guestOSAltName[^(]+\((?<ARCH>\d{2}).*/xm) {
         print "$+{ARCH}\n";
    } else {
         print "N/A\n";
    }
}
```

Start the demo:

```
$ perl t.pl
Ubuntu Linux
64
Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition
N/A
```

Comment: No go with the example given, also I found out that the guest OS part of my expression needs to be greedy, if I make it non greedy like you recommended it stops at the first whitespace.

Comment: I am trying to strip off the whitespace and the (64-bit) part of the line. It might also say (32-bit).

Comment: I've changed the regex to __/^guestOSAltName[^"]+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+?)\s\\(.*$/__.

Comment: Awesome it works against "Ubuntu Linux" BUT when I tried it against "Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Standard Edition" the if statment jumps to the else statment which is print "N/A" So it is almost there.

Comment: Update: __/^guestOSAltName[^"]+"(?<GUEST_OS>.+?)\s*[\\("]+.*$/__

Answer (score 0):

Generally find that `.*` is too powerful (as you are finding!). Two suggestions

Be more explicit on what you are looking for

```
    my $text = '( something ) ( something else) ' ;

    $text =~ /
      \(
      ( [\s\w]+ )
      \)
        /x ;

    print $1 ;
```

Use non greedy matching

```
    my $text = '( something ) ( something else) ' ;

    $text =~ /
      \(
      ( .*? )   # non greedy match
      \)
        /x ;

    print $1 ;
```

General observation - involved regexps are far easier to read if you use the `/x` option as this allows spacing and comments.

Comment: I tied using you sample, but when I made it more specific it stopped too soon, so instead of Microsoft Windows Server 2003, I just got Microsoft.